# How to omit a certain substring out of an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsstring

I would like to know how it is possible to omit a specific substring out an NSString, assuming the NSString does contain that substring.

**For example:**

Original string: "This is a string *but these words should be omitted*."

Substring to omit: "*but these words should be omitted*".

Result string: "This is a string."

Thanks ahead,
iLyrical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `NSString`'s `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`. You may also want to trim the trailing whitespace with `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *originalString = @"This is a string but these words should be omitted.";
NSString *substringToOmit = @" but these words should be omitted";
NSString *resultString = [originalString stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:substringToOmit
                                                                  withString:@""];
```